# Need help to understand this proof of the question number $51$ of the $7$th chapter given in Gallian's Contemporary abstract Algebra.

Tags: group-theory, logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Q. Prove that $A_5$ has no subgroup of order $30.$

Now at the end of the book he has given an outline of the proof as follows :

> Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $A_5$ of order $30.$ We claim that $H$ contains all $20$ elements of $A_5$ that have order $3.$ To verify this, assume that there is some $\alpha$ in $A_5$ of order $3$ that is not in $H$. Then $A_5=H \cup \alpha H$. It follows that $\alpha^2 H=H$ or $\alpha^ 2H=\alpha H$. Since the latter implies that $\alpha \in H$, we have that $\alpha^2 H =H$, which implies that $\alpha^2 \in H$. But then $\langle \alpha \rangle= \langle \alpha^2 \rangle \subseteq H.$ Which is a contradiction of our assumption that $\alpha$ is not in $H$. Since $|H|=30$, we have a contradiction.

In this outline of proof he assumes $\alpha \notin H$ and by following deductions he achieves $\alpha \in H$. This then supposedly implies that our assumption that $\alpha \notin H$ was false and thus every $\alpha$ of order $3$ is in $H$. Isn't it that he should have achieved contradiction in some other fact regarding $A_5$?

I mean when we prove $A \implies B$ by contradiction, we  assume $\sim B$ to be true and after some deductions we get contradiction that $A$ is false rather than $B$ is true. Here we have "$H$ is a subgroup of order $30 \implies$ all elements of $A_5$ of order $3$ belong to $H$." So we assume there exists such an element not in $H$. In both of the cases that follow, we find that that element is in $H$. I think this is paradoxical somehow. That is $\alpha \notin H \implies \alpha \in H.$

Please help me to get clear picture of what is going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last statement is the contradiction!

Any fact given or that can be deduced from the given assumptions could give an acceptable contradiction. In your case, you assumed an element does not belong to $H$. Then using some arguments you had two possible cases about the group. Considering these two cases raised a statement which is a contradiction to **your** original assumption.

You assumed something is true and then showed that if it is true then it is false too! That can't happen hence you must be wrong in the first place.

For an alternate proof of the theorem, you can observe that if there was a subgroup of $A_5$ of order $30,$ it's index would be $2$ hence it would be normal. Hence, every element of order relatively prime to $2$ would lie in $H$. Thus, $H$ contains all elements of order $3$.

Comment: 1) Which last statement of mine did you mean is a contradiction? 2)Also I haven't written a proof; I have given my interpretation of Gallian's proof that : $\alpha \notin H \implies \alpha \in H$. Which I think is paradoxical. 3)As you have written that the two cases raised a statement which is a contradiction to my original assumption; did you mean the assumption that $\alpha \notin H$? Thanks!

Comment: $\alpha \notin H \implies \alpha \in H$ is a contradiction. You showed that something is true implies it is false. That means if it happens then it doesn't happen. This is a contradiction. As $\alpha$ either has to be in $H$ or not. You may think of it this way: you took an element in complement of a set and showed that this implies it is in the set. This implies the element has to lie in their intersection which is the empty set. This gives a contradiction as empty set is well, empty.

Comment: Well, I have never seen such kinda proof before hence was perplexed. I have seen proofs which are like this for example : Ques.)Prove that a closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R$ is compact. Ans. - Suppose that set is not compact, then we deduce that either the set is not closed or it is not bounded. Did you get me? We didn't deduce that the set is compact. Exactly, this I want to emphasize here that if $\alpha \notin H$ then something else contradictory should happen. I hope you understand my concern. :D

Comment: After going through various sources on internet I came to understand this pretty well. Now I got what you are saying. Learnt something new today. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No not at all. He assumes $\alpha \notin H$, and then goes on to prove that $\alpha ^{2} \in H$, which is a contradiction as it cannot happen. Hence $\alpha$ must belong to $H$. Contradiction is in the fact that if there is no $\alpha$ in a subgroup, there is no $\alpha ^{2}$ in that subgroup, since $\alpha$ is a three cycle.

Comment: But $\langle \alpha \rangle = \langle \alpha^2 \rangle \subseteq H \implies \alpha \in H$.

Answer (score 1):

$((\neg B)\implies B)\implies B\implies ((\neg A)\lor B)\iff (A\implies B).$